# How can i copy from a .NET Bitmap all pixels to av_image frame data?

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I just created a new function in my c++ project using an example with Bitmap lock bits:

```
void GetFrameData(Bitmap ^b)
    {

        typedef System::Drawing::Rectangle R;
        R rect = R(0,0,b->Width,b->Height);
        System::Drawing::Imaging::BitmapData^ bmpData = b->LockBits( rect, System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, b->PixelFormat );
        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData->Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
        // This code is specific to a bitmap with 24 bits per pixels. 
       int bytes = Math::Abs(bmpData->Stride) * b->Height;
       array<Byte>^rgbValues = gcnew array<Byte>(bytes);

       // Copy the RGB values into the array.
      System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy( ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes );

      // Set every third value to 255.   
     for ( int counter = 2; counter < rgbValues->Length; counter += 3 )
      rgbValues[ counter ] = 255;

     // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
    System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::Copy( rgbValues, 0, ptr, bytes );

    // Unlock the bits.
    b->UnlockBits( bmpData );
    }
```

The function get a bitmap file from CSHARP and somehow i need to use this lockbits to copy the pixels from the bitmap to this function:

```
void Encoder_start(char *filename)
{
    printf("Encode video file %s\n", filename);
    /* open it */
    if (avcodec_open2(c, codec, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open codec\n");
        exit(1);
    }
//    f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    errn = fopen_s(&f,filename, "wb");

    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    }


    frame = avcodec_alloc_frame();
    if (!frame) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate video frame\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    frame->format = c->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = c->width;
    frame->height = c->height;
    /* the image can be allocated by any means and av_image_alloc() is
     * just the most convenient way if av_malloc() is to be used */
//    ret = av_image_alloc(frame->data, frame->linesize, c->width, c->height,
  //                       c->pix_fmt, 32);

     frame->data[0] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[1] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[2] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[3] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[4] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[5] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[6] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);
     frame->data[7] = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(1000000);

     if (frame->data[7]==0) {
    //if (ret < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate raw picture buffer\n");
        exit(1);
    }

     total_frame_counter=0;
}



void Encoder_push_frame()
{
    /* encode 1 second of video */
   // for(i=0;i<25;i++) {
        av_init_packet(&pkt);
        pkt.data = NULL;    // packet data will be allocated by the encoder
        pkt.size = 0;
        fflush(stdout);
        /* prepare a dummy image */
        /* Y */
        for(y=0;y<c->height;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width;x++) {
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }
        /* Cb and Cr */
        for(y=0;y<c->height/2;y++) {
            for(x=0;x<c->width/2;x++) {
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }
        frame->pts = total_frame_counter;

        total_frame_counter++;

        /* encode the image */
        ret = avcodec_encode_video2(c, &pkt, frame, &got_output);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error encoding frame\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (got_output) {
            printf("Write frame %3d (size=%5d)\n", total_frame_counter, pkt.size);
            fwrite(pkt.data, 1, pkt.size, f);
            av_free_packet(&pkt);
        }
   // }

}
```

I'm not sure how to fill and with what the av_malloc i set it to 1000000 each place for the testing.

And the Encoder_push_frame function should get the pixels or maybe it's with the av_malloc the idea is to fill the image in the push_frame function with pixels from the Bitmap.

I tried a lot of ways but it didn't work at all.

**EDIT**

I'm using this code:

```
void GetFrameData(Bitmap ^b)
    {
        auto bmpData = b->LockBits( System::Drawing::Rectangle(0,0,b->Width,b->Height), ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb );

    // The beginning of the bitmap data in memory
    char* top = bmpData->Scan0.ToPointer();

    // find bitmap data for the top row (if bottom-up bitmap, this is at the end)
    if (bmpData->Stride < 0) {
        top += Stride * (1 - b->Height);
    }

    for( int y = 0; y < b->Height; ++y ) {
        RGBTRIPLE* row = (RGBTRIPLE*)(top + y * bmpData->Stride);

        // saturate red channel
        for( int x = 0; x < b->Width; ++x ) {
            row[x].rgbtBlue = 255;
            row[x].rgbtGreen = 255;
            row[x].rgbtRed = 255;
    }

    // Unlock the bits.
    b->UnlockBits( bmpData );
    }
```

In the Rectangle i had to change it to: System::Drawing::Rectangle if not then i had an error on the Rectangle that it's having a conflict with another Rectangle.
But after changed it now i have an error on the bmpData on this line:

```
char* top = bmpData->Scan0.ToPointer();
```

IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "char *"

The second error is on the Stride:

```
top += Stride * (1 - b->Height);
```

The error: IntelliSense: identifier "Stride" is undefined

How can i fix this errors.

And:

Changed the for loop to:

```
for( int x = 0; x < b->Width; ++x ) {
            row[x].rgbtBlue = 255;
            row[x].rgbtGreen = 255;
            row[x].rgbtRed = 255;
```

The reason i changed it is that you did row[x].R = 255; but R is not exist/defined so what should i do in this for how to fix it ? ( i guess what i did is wrong ).

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother copying the data from `Scan0` into a new array.  The bitmap data is not subject to being moved by the garbage collector, and C++ is perfectly able to work with the data in place, using a pointer cast.

Something like

```
#include <windows.h>
void GetFrameData(Bitmap ^b)
{
    using System::Drawing::Imaging::ImageLockMode;
    using System::Drawing::Imaging::PixelFormat;
    using System::Drawing::Rectangle;
    auto bmpData = b->LockBits( Rectangle(0,0,b->Width,b->Height), ImageLockMode::ReadWrite, PixelFormat::Format24bppRgb );

    // The beginning of the bitmap data in memory
    char* top = (char*)bmpData->Scan0.ToPointer();

    // find bitmap data for the top row (if bottom-up bitmap, this is at the end)
    if (bmpData->Stride < 0) {
        top += bmpData->Stride * (1 - b->Height);
    }

    for( int y = 0; y < b->Height; ++y ) {
        RGBTRIPLE* row = (RGBTRIPLE*)(top + y * bmpData->Stride);

        // saturate red channel
        for( int x = 0; x < b->Width; ++x ) {
           row[x].rgbtRed = 255;
    }

    // Unlock the bits.
    b->UnlockBits( bmpData );
}
```

Now you can use these RGB values to calulate Y/Cr/Cb values as you fill in your av_format image.  (Or just tell av_format the image is RGB)

Comment: @YaronCohenMinz: Took me a minute, but I think this code should be a good start.

Comment: Ben Voigt i used your code and had to change something and i have two errors can you please look at my question im editing it now.

Comment: Ben i just updated my question if you can look at it please. Thank you.

Comment: @YaronCohenMinz: Yes, I had a couple small mistakes.  The errors you found should be gone now.